# How to grep a column?

Tags: bash, grep

Sorry guys, i would like to know, if it possible to grep column? For example, we have output like (vmstat):

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0 706108  75536 328172    0    0   142    88  489 1042  5 11 84  0
```

If I run `./script.sh in` output will be:

```
$ ./script.sh in
$ 489
```

Or maybe not grep, but i need use only bash (preparing for the exam). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `| tail -n1 | awk '{print $11;}'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you wanted was, you gave a column title as argument, like `in`, `buff` or `wa`... and you get the corresponding value.

so try this:

```
vmstat|awk -v f="in" '!o{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x==f){o=1;next}}o{print $x}'
```

here the `f="in"` is the column header. `"in"` was hardcoded, it could be shell variable like `f="$foo"`

small test, I saved your vmstat output as `out` file:

```
kent$  cat out
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0 706108  75536 328172    0    0   142    88  489 1042  5 11 84  0

kent$  awk -v f="in" '!o{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x==f){o=1;next}}o{print $x}' out
489

kent$  awk -v f="buff" '!o{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)if($x==f){o=1;next}}o{print $x}' out         
75536
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use awk to get the value based on the column **name**:

```
vmstat | 
awk -v col="in" '
    NR==2 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == col) break} 
    NR==3 {print $i}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch` inside your bash script + `awk` command should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to get a column.

`vmstat | cut -b 57-60`

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come up with the following:

Suppose, you have a file having the following lines in a file named `test.txt`:

`abe 123 bdb 532`

`xyz 593 iau 591`

Now you want to find the lines which include the first field having the first and last letters as vowels. If you did a simple grep you would get both of the lines but the following will give you the first line only which is the desired output:

```
egrep "^([0-z]{1,} ){0}[aeiou][0-z]+[aeiou]" test.txt
```

Then you want to the find the lines which include the third field having the first and last letters as vowels. Similary, if you did a simple grep you would get both of the lines but the following will give you the second line only which is the desired output:

```
egrep "^([0-z]{1,} ){2}[aeiou][0-z]+[aeiou]" test.txt
```

The value in the first curly braces `{1,}` specifies that the preceding character which ranges from 0 to z according to the ASCII table, can occur any number of times. After that, we have the field separator space in this case. Change the value within the second curly braces `{0} or {2} to the desired field number-1`. Then, use a regular expression to mention your criteria.